# Error inflating class ImageButton Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable (missing name) #0x7f0800cc

Tags: android

Recently we are cing somany issues in playstore with these issues

found currently in Brand:LGE
Model:Nexus 5X with version OS version 8.1 but where as we are unable to replicate